# How to start a child process on linux/python that can end itself without becoming a zombie?

Tags: linux, python-3.x

In python3, is it possible to create a child process from a parent process, and with the child process able to completely kill itself, without the parent process to wait for something, or do any other stuff?

With `os.fork` it seems that the parent process need to wait until the child process is finished. This is not what I want. I want the parent process to go on without the need to check the status of it's child processes.

What is the most simple way to achieve this in python under Linux?